# Creating field with cumulative values of line length in QGIS

Tags: qgis, line, fields-attributes, expression, length

I've been through some of the examples and solutions posted here for calculating chainage of a line or cumulative values. However, I am still unable to achieve the desired outcome.

What I am trying to do is to add the `"Length"` values by `"row number"`. So the `"Chg"`(Chainage) i.e. a cumulative value of line section 1 = 7.69026, 2 = 14.83986, 3 = 22.69265 ... etc. Is there an expression I can use in field calculator to achieve this?

[image]

Comment: Dear @JohnF, please keep in mind: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

+1 for the custom function, they are a good trick to have up your sleeve.

In this case you can do it with the built-in [`aggregate()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#aggregate)function:

```
aggregate('Line_CHain', 'sum', "Length", "id"<=attribute(@parent, 'id'))
```

Comment: Thank you M Bain that worked a treat. Nice one! Thanks also Louis Cottereau. I didn't try the script but will at some point. Cheers

Answer (score 6):

In your Field Calculator, go into the Function Editor, create a new file, insert this function:

```py
"""
Define new functions using @qgsfunction. feature and parent must always be the
last args. Use args=-1 to pass a list of values as arguments
"""

from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
import sys
if sys.version_info.major == 3:
    layer_registry = QgsProject
else:
    layer_registry = QgsMapLayerRegistry

@qgsfunction(args="auto", group='Custom')
def get_length_feature(layer_id, feature, parent):
    id = feature.id()
    len_tot = 0.
    for feat in layer_registry.instance().mapLayer(layer_id).getFeatures():
        if feat["id"] <= feature["id"]:
            len_tot += feat.geometry().length()
    return len_tot
```

Load it, return into the expression tab and insert the following:
`get_length_feature(@layer_id)`

Comment: This will for each segment add all prevoius segments. That may not be a concern when your line has fewer than (say) a million segments, but runtime will grow exponentially (as far as i can math ;) ).

Comment: True, so would the other answer also. However in that case i would definitely not do it like this, and i wouldn't use a million independant features also to do an incremental distance calcul. In that case i would do it programmaticaly with a single feature containing all the points as either a linestring or multilinestring